# Node.js sending data to vps server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to send data from client.js to the server hosted on vps and then return to client.js another data.

Something like this: client.js >data> server.js >data2> client.js

My client.js file:

```
var http = require('http');

var option = {
    hostname : "51.x.x.x" ,
    port : 8000 ,
    //data?: "{}",
    method : "POST",
    path : "/"
} 

    var request = http.request(option , function(resp){
       resp.on("data",function(chunck){
           console.log(chunck.toString());
       });
    });
    request.end(); 
/* server.js sending data to client.js but I don't know how to send data to server.js */
```

and server.js file

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method == 'POST') {
        console.log('Res > post');
        res.end('data from server.js (post)')
    }
    else {
        console.log("Res > get");
        res.end('data form server.js (get)');
    }
}).listen(8000);
console.log('Running server with port 8000...');
```

So, is there any way to send data from client.js to server.js ?

Comment: can you explain it more  !!!!

Comment: for example: client.js is sending key ex. 5 to server.js which is responding to client.js with callback 5*2 = 10

Answer (score 0):

Is your client.js also a node application? If so, websockets might help you to establish a two way communication.
https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: Thanks, I will check it. And yes, it's node application